# Loading WordPress Admin Environment

Tags: plugin-development, cron

I am using the following library to create custom posts:
https://github.com/HarriBellThomas/Wordpress_PostController

It works perfectly, however I wanted to use it as stand alone custom_post.php file to run through CRON job to automatically create new posts. To achieve this I have add the following line to my main custom_post.php file:

```
 if ( ! defined('ABSPATH') ) {
     /** Set up WordPress environment */
     require_once( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-load.php' );
 }
```

When I run this file through browser it works perfectly and adds a new post with custom Title, selects Category, adds new thumbnail and sets desired author.

Then I setup the CRON job, which creates new post, sets thumbnail, selects category, adds desired author BUT the post CONTENT is empty. Then I figured out it only adds the post CONTENT when I am logged in to Admin in any of the browser.

How can either I login or load admin environment to make this happen and it adds the post CONTENT. Secondly, is there any restriction while adding post_content ONLY for admins or allowed users ?..

Comment: You should use WP CLI instead

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that iFrame was being stripped, I tried all methods to allow iFrame code butdidn't work, so I wrote a simple short-code and now it works.